# NPE not occuring or being caught in Servlet

Tags: java, json, servlets, error-handling

I have a pretty basic Servlet

```
public class DreambearLoginServlet extends HttpServlet {

    @Override
    public void doGet(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp) throws ServletException, IOException {

        JSONObject ret = new JSONObject();

        try {

            // handle the request
            try {

                String action = req.getParameter("action");

                if (action.equals("login")) {

                    ...

                } else if (action.equals("checklogin")) {

                    ...

                } else {
                    throw new RuntimeException("Action invalid");
                }

            } catch (Exception e) {
                ret.put("error", e.getMessage());
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            // write response
            resp.setContentType("application/json");
        resp.getWriter().print(ret.toString());
            resp.getWriter().flush();

        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }

    }



}
```

Now, if I call this without specifying the query string parameter `action`, a `NullPointerException` should be thrown upon the statement `action.equals("login")`. This would result in the catch code being executed and the JSON output being `{"error": "Whatever NPE says"}`. Strangely enough, the JSON output is just `{}`. How could this be?

Comment: the results you see imply that either 1) there is a NPE caused elsewhere before the code in question is executed or 2) the code shown here is not actually what is being executed (i.e. maybe you are testing an outdated version). Are you sure neither is occuring? do you have a stacktrace that points to the exact line where the NPE is generated?

Comment: That's the thing, I see no evidence at all of the NPE. There also shouldn't be any exception before the second try statement because there is JSON output (which is written inside the first try block), it's just empty.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`e.getMessage()` is `null` for `NullPointerException` and JSONObject.put() documentation says:

> Put a key/value pair in the
>   JSONObject. *If the value is null, then
>   the key will be removed from the
>   JSONObject if it is present*.

So, as expected, nothing is added to your JSON object.

Comment: That's indeed the problem. What a strange API design decision by the JSON group; JSON supports keys with "null" values, doesn't it? Anyway, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You are correct, if a NPE happens it will be caught by your catch clause.
So you are right, it cannot be!

- are you sure it's a get request?
- are you sure your code is not stopping somewhere else?
- is action maybe set to empty?
- is maybe the message in NullPointerException empty?